# Image not visible in magnified preview in website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added a Image Zoom in my website using the following instruction: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp
But after adding that image not visible in zoomed box while mouse over the image.Its appear blank inside.

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide code that you have tried

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle of your code so we can look into it.

Comment: I was trying it to eccommerce website product image

Comment: How to zoom images like amazon website using css,jquery or free plugins